# Change bar color in Chart based on X-axis title in Excle

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I want to change bar color of a chart based on Quarter-Quarter grouping in an exported excel file automatically, with the least manual work.  I tried VBA to do that, but blocked by not knowing how to get X-axis title.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select

'Check bar caption
'If bar captioin = 'FY13 Q1' then do following...

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

My question:

1. Is VBA the best way to do that?
2. Is there any better way?  Can some excel built-in function already support to do it?
3. If I want to automate the whole process as much as possible, how to integrate macro to the exported excel file without creating macro-->copying-->pasting.

Comment: I got an error (<Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object>) when debuging to 'IF ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues(1) = "FY13 Q1" THEN ... END IF', who can give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would use VBA yes, but then that's just what I work with
2. The property you're looking for is

`ActiveSheet.Charts("Chart 1").Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text`

3. To make sure the macro is available in all worksheets, create an addin file and ask future users to install it. You didn't mention what version of Excel you're using, but the Excel 2010 reference on Addins is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx

EDIT: rereading your post I think you may have meant to ask about Data Labels rather than the X-Axis Title. In which case you'll want to use:

`ActiveSheet.Charts("Chart 1").SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text`

Now with this and the above, you'll want to make sure the Title/Data Label exists first, for example with :

`If ActiveSheet.Charts("Chart 1").SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).HasDataLabel Then...`

If you need help with this, or with looping through the charts /points, it's probably best to look for the answer first and ask a separate question if you can't find.

Cheers!